# Using PHP, how do I reliably identify (find) a known Javascript variable name in a source string?

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Let's say I have a PHP string that contains the following text, or some other text that is valid Javascript code if put into an interpreter:

**$js_script PHP variable**

```
var loaded = [];
var loading = [];
var downloading = [];

function load(name)
{
    loading.push(name);
    downloading.push(name);

    // do some asynchronous stuff, with the following callback:
    (function () {
        loaded.push(name);
        downloading = [];
    });
}
```

I want to replace the variable `loading` (as in replace the variable name itself in the entire code) to `l1`, *without* using a full javascript parser, and thus producing the following output:

**$js_script PHP variable**

```
var loaded = [];
var l1 = [];
var downloading = [];

function load(name)
{
    l1.push(name);
    downloading.push(name);

    // do some asynchronous stuff, with the following callback:
    (function () {
        loaded.push(name);
        downloading = [];
    });
}
```

**The reasons I assume avoiding using a parser is a good choice:**

- they seem to be *extreme* overkill for this single task,
- this is the only modification I wish to perform on the input code,
- I explicitly know the variable name I'm going to replace.

I'm not concerned with performance, since the resulting output is to be cached. I thought about using regex for this, that is, finding all occurrences of *"loading"* in the code-string using:

```
\bloading\b(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

... which obviously doesn't support apostrophes yet, but other than that, seems to handle the task right so far.

Is there something I'm missing? I know that JavaScript in wholesale is not a regular language, but how about this part? Should I forget about using regex, and utilize a parser instead?

Comment: Was going to suggest `str_replace()`, yet it might be best to use `preg_replace()`. With RegEx you can cover more scenarios. '/\sloading\s/', '/loading\./' etc.

Comment: Curious to know what problem you're trying to solve there.. seems like this would be prone to failures.

Comment: @Hamish I'd like to achieve a lightweight, simple compression of select variable names to: 1.) save bandwidth, 2.) hide part of logic behind various functionalities. My regex holds the line so far, but as you said, this might be prone to failures, hence the question.

Comment: @JánosWeisz In that case, use something like Closure compiler to minify the script and use gzip to compress the stream delivered by the server. JS should be static too - you can save yourself hassle/cost by putting it on a CDN or static host instead of the MASSIVE performance hit that running it through PHP entails.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `preg_replace`, it's pretty simple:

```
$out = preg_replace("/(\W)(loading)(\W)/", "$1l1$3", $in);
```

An example can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/jK3oD0/1).

**EDIT:** I did a quick benchmark, and running one replace like this on the file you specified took my computer ~2 μs on average (I put the benchmarking code [here](http://www.tehplayground.com/#ue9NUuhVr))